# How to override default DNS

Tags: go, dns, resolve

I've been working on finding a way to try and override the default DNS server for a Go program for a while but still with no success sadly.

The current solution which I had thought would work was:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    DNS := "1.1.1.1"
    net.DefaultResolver = &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: true,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            d := net.Dialer{
                Timeout: time.Millisecond * time.Duration(3000),
            }
            return d.DialContext(ctx, "udp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:53", DNS))
        },
    }

    resp, err := net.LookupHost("tsdfsdf.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", resp)
}
```

But the response from this is:

```
lookup tsdfsdf.com on 192.168.0.1:53: no such host[]
```

Which is sadly my default DNS server set in my reslov.conf
I have tried forcing to use the Go Resolver by setting `export GODEBUG=netdns=go`

The long term solution is to be able to over the default resolver for the HTTP Client which would, in turn be consumed by some AWS SDK stuff.

Has any faced this or knows how I can get around this?

FYI, I know "tsdfsdf.com" is not a real domain I'm just using it to spit a No such host error to see what DNS it asked.

Comment: The error is misleading because you're ignoring the address parameter. The error message is constructed by Dial's caller (which assumes you're connecting to address), and your hard-coded address can't possibly appear in it. Use something like tcpdump or Wireshark and you'll see the DNS query go to CloudFlare.

Comment: Yeah that did show up correctly using wireshark, didn't even cross my mind.
I did find out thou when using the AWS Sdk i had to create a custom Http Client with Transport and Dialer for it to take :) 

Will post what i used below :)

Answer (score 1):

The instance of `net.Resolver` does not know that you're not dialing the address that it requested in the `address` argument of the `Dial` function, it thinks that it's dialing `192.168.0.1:53`, so when your `DNS := "1.1.1.1"` can't find the host, the error message mentions the address that it requested to dial, not the address that your dialer actually dialed.